# .net core: ICollection in model always empty

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework, linq, .net-core

I'm trying to add values to my exists model's ICollection but when I trying to catch it in the next time, my ICollection is empty.

there is my code and

Model:

```
    public class OrderDetails
{
    [Key]
    public int OrderID { get; set; }
    public int UserID { get; set; }
    public DateTime OrderTime { get; set; }
    public double Total { get; set; }   
    public virtual ICollection<Product> Cart { get; set; }
}
```

}

entering values to my ICollection:

```
 OrderDetails order = new OrderDetails();

        order.UserID = u.ID;
        // I have tried this also:
        //
        // foreach(Product p in productsCollection)
        //{
        //    order.Cart.Add(p);
        //}
        // the productsCollection is a List that contains values...
        //
        order.Cart = productsCollection; // this is my problem
        order.OrderTime =DateTime.Now;
        order.Total = sum;
        _context.OrderDetails.Add(order);
        _context.SaveChanges();
        return Redirect("/Index");
```

trying to catch it again with an OrderID:

```
            OrderDetails orderDetails = _context.OrderDetails
                                  .Where(ood => ood.OrderID == 18)
                                  .Include("Cart")
                                  .FirstOrDefault();
```

there are 2 screenshots that can demonstrate my problem:

1) the cart is empty :
[when trying to catch the cart:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Jb0oE.png)

2) dbcontext at the same time:
[but when checking my dbcontext it contains the values:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2rqhT.png)

** note that sometimes the cart can be 1 in the count, 2 or 0 ..
I can't explain why and when that's occurred.

Comment: Can you post the code where you set the productsCollection variable

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Might be, you're just mixing up numbers. From your screenshots can be seen that the order with the `OrderID` of 18 has an empty cart; the order with the `OrderID` of 32 has products in its cart.

The latter order has an index of 18 in the list of orders. This has nothing to do with the `OrderID`.

Answer (score 0):

If I understood your problem correctly, you want to get the value that has just updated.
You could achieve this by calling the instance object just after it is updated like below:

```
OrderDetails order = new OrderDetails();

        order.UserID = u.ID;
        order.Cart = productsCollection;
        order.OrderTime =DateTime.Now;
        order.Total = sum;
        _context.OrderDetails.Add(order);
        _context.SaveChanges();
        var Id = order.OrderID //or whatever info you want from the updated query.
        return Redirect("/Index");
```

I hope it helps.

Comment: Hi. thanks for your reply. I mean that when I'm trying to get my ICollection sometime in the future, it will be empty (count = 0 instead count='num of products'

Comment: The count of the ICollection will be same as number of elements `productsCollection` in `order.Cart = productsCollection;` which you are passing in the query. So if your `productsCollection` has 0 elements then `cart` count will be 0 and so on.

Comment: Sure, I checked my productsCollection - it contains values when I'm trying to insert it to my order.Cart... Maybe this is a async call or something like this? I can't understand what is the problem here ... @Vinod

Comment: Just try this line after `saveChanges()` and check what value `Id` in `var Id = order.OrderID` holds, this way you will more clearly able to find if the data is updating as you intended.

Comment: ok - I recognized my problem: when I'm setting a product to some another ICollection, it takes the instance from one to another. so now what can I do?

Comment: Make sure that the `productsCollection` must be of type `ICollection<Product>` or `List<Product>`. You can do it something like this `Product obj = new Product()                                                                            
  obj.FirstProperty="Your value";                                                                                            
  obj.SecondProperty="Your value"  //and so on.
  List<Product> productsCollection = new List<Product>                                 
  productsCollection.Add(obj )`

Answer (score 0):

As written you have two confusingly different ways to add Products to an OrderDetails:  Adding to the Cart, and replacing the Cart with a different Cart.  Best to have just one.  So make your Entity:

```
public class OrderDetails
{
    [Key]
    public int OrderID { get; set; }
    public int UserID { get; set; }
    public DateTime OrderTime { get; set; }
    public double Total { get; set; }   
    public virtual ICollection<Product> Cart { get; } = new HashSet<Product>();
}
```

Now an OrderDetails entity *always* has a Cart, which might be empty.